# how to print into jtext Area when i press a button the Result of stringbuilder

Tags: java

i have this code and i want to know how to print       //System.out.println(**result**);  into jtext Area when i press a button.

I tryed with text.settext(result);
tryed with text.settext(result.toString());

i`m out of ideeas

```
package nioCount;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Component;
public class Settings 
{






public static void main(String...args) throws IOException {

    String line = null;
    Pattern category = Pattern.compile("^\\[(.*?)\\]$"); // matches [Cars]
    Pattern itemAndQuantity = Pattern.compile("^(\\w+)=(\\d+)$"); // matches Lamborghini=6
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    {


    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/test.txt"))) {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Matcher categoryMatcher = category.matcher(line);
            Matcher itemMatcher = itemAndQuantity.matcher(line);
            if (categoryMatcher.matches()) {
                if (result.length() > 0) { // found new category, put on new line
                    result.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                }
                String categoryName = categoryMatcher.group(1); // Cars
                result.append(categoryName).append(": "); // Cars: 
            } else if (itemMatcher.matches()) {
                String item = itemMatcher.group(1); // Lamborghini
                String quantity = itemMatcher.group(2); // 6
                result.append(item).append(" ") // Lamborghini
                      .append(quantity) // Lamborghini 6
                      .append(", "); // Lamborghini 6,
            }
        }


        // we are done processing the file, output the result
        //System.out.println(result);


        }
        JTextArea text;
        text = new JTextArea(result.toString());

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        frame.setAutoRequestFocus(false);


        //text.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
       // text.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        text.setEditable(false);
        text.setBounds(100, 92, 436, 195);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.getContentPane().add(text);
        frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700,500));


        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Count");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Reader in = null;

            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(100, 385, 134, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

        JButton btnResetCount = new JButton("Reset Count");
        btnResetCount.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                text.setText(null);

            }
        });
        btnResetCount.setBounds(402, 385, 134, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnResetCount);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }




}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **fastest way** to do what you want would be:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Settings
{

public static void main(String... args) throws IOException
{
        String result = aMethodThatReadsTheFileAndReturnsAString();

        JTextArea text = new JTextArea(result);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        frame.setAutoRequestFocus(false);
        text.setEditable(false);
        text.setBounds(100, 92, 436, 195);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.getContentPane().add(text);
        frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 500));

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Count");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
                {
                    text.setText(aMethodThatReadsTheFileAndReturnsAString());
                }
            });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(100, 385, 134, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

        JButton btnResetCount = new JButton("Reset Count");
        btnResetCount.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    text.setText("");

                }
            });
        btnResetCount.setBounds(402, 385, 134, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnResetCount);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}

public static String aMethodThatReadsTheFileAndReturnsAString()
{
    String line = null;
    Pattern category = Pattern.compile("^\\[(.*?)\\]$"); // matches [Cars]
    Pattern itemAndQuantity = Pattern.compile("^(\\w+)=(\\d+)$"); // matches
                                                                    // Lamborghini=6
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("result @"+new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date())+" is: \n");
    {

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "D:/test.txt")))
        {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                Matcher categoryMatcher = category.matcher(line);
                Matcher itemMatcher = itemAndQuantity.matcher(line);
                if (categoryMatcher.matches())
                {
                    if (result.length() > 0)
                    { // found new category, put on new line
                        result.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                    }
                    String categoryName = categoryMatcher.group(1); // Cars
                    result.append(categoryName).append(": "); // Cars:
                }
                else if (itemMatcher.matches())
                {
                    String item = itemMatcher.group(1); // Lamborghini
                    String quantity = itemMatcher.group(2); // 6
                    result.append(item).append(" ") // Lamborghini
                            .append(quantity) // Lamborghini 6
                            .append(", "); // Lamborghini 6,
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception x)
        {
            result.append(x.toString());
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
}
}
```

or `text.appendText(aMethodThatReadsTheFileAndReturnsAString())` if you prefer to add the output to the end of what already is displayed in the TextArea.

The **correct way** would be to start reading when the button is pressed and display the result after the operation. The reading should be done by another Thread started just for that purpose. You might want to read about [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: Not working, if i change the values from Test.txt and press the count button it won`t update

Comment: @clopotziel If you just changed the part I posted it will always display the content the file had at startup. You will have to move the reading into the action listener as only the code in the listener is run when you press the button. I updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: ya i know but i don`t know what method to add at action listener

Comment: got an ideea how to fix this?

Comment: Are you serious? You have just to extract your complete initialization of result into a method and call it every time the button is pressed and set the TextArea like shown above.

Comment: don`t know how to do that.. not so "pro"

Comment: could u add me an example please?

Comment: Done. But it might be missing some curly braces ^_^